# how to add two textbox values(data) to a single column into data base(My sql)?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, textbox

i am developing a website under asp.net using mysql.

In that I have two text box so i want to add those two textbox values into database in a single cloumn..
these are two text box..

```
<asp: TextBox ID="mytextbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp: TextBox ID="mytextbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In My data Base i am adding various text-box fields in one table.. i mean i am adding one value to one column But at this part i need to add these two textbox values into a single column of a table in database(mysql)..

Let us suppose address field..
i need to display the **address1** and **address2** values i need to add those two fields to a Single column and display in some other Page as a single Textbox..
**and the database must be mysql..**

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: Adding multiple text box values into one column smells of a very bad design. You should not do it unless you can strongly justify the reason for doing it.

Comment: pass textBox1.Text+textBox2.Text to insert query

Comment: hi Nitin Varpe sir... its working thanks... Thanks immediate Responce...

Comment: Its great Madhu.. you are giving the answer with the  Nitin Varpe  name.. Thats Spirit. in stackoverflow every one copy and gain their reputation You are not like that.. Thats the spirit keepit up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the valuse of Two textbox into a single column

```
Insert into tablename(colomnname) values (mytextbox1.Text + mytextbox2.Text);
```

and if you want to store those values then you can use .Trim() option like

```
Insert into tablename(colomnname) values (mytextbox1.Text.Trim() + mytextbox2.Text.Trim());
```

This worked fine for me and i am using the database MySql.
Thanks to user Nitin Varpe For Hint..

Answer (score 2):

First, your text boxes text size (together) must not exceed the size of the database column that you want to store their values in

Second, in server page:

you just have to get their values concatenated: `myText1.text + ' ' + myText2.text`
You have to make sure that you use `SqlCommand.Parameters` to insure that you are safe from Sql Injections.

So assuming that you have 
supposing you defined a connection

```
string commandText = "UPDATE YourTableName SET YourColumnName = @myAddress WHERE ...etc;";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@myAddress ", SqlDbType.Text);
        command.Parameters["@myAddress "].Value = myText1.text + ' ' + myText2.text;
```

Comment: hi simsim its k But i mentioned the Database must be Mysql.. because my website is verybig and its 99% designed  in my sql